# JSON parsing is not working

Tags: ios, json, parsing

Im trying to parse and show json content in my tableViewCell, but something goes wrong.

JSON Here: http://bumpee.net/xcode/index.php

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *arr = [json objectForKey:@"feed"];
    for(NSDictionary *aaa in arr) {
        NSDictionary *one = [aaa objectForKey:@"1"];
        NSString *onePrint= [one objectForKey:@"name"];
        [array addObject:onePrint];
    }

    [[self tableView ] reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Describe what goes wrong... What debugging have you done? Is the JSON downloaded properly? Any serialisation error (not that your code shows you checking...)?

Comment: What goes wrong? When you NSLog(@"%@", json); does it exist? Are you using the right keys?

Comment: I didn't know that Xcode was ever expected to work with JSON.

Comment: There is no array in that JSON string.  Why are you assigning the parse result to an NSArray???  Pulleeese go to json.org and learn the syntax!  (And don't just blindly copy someone else's work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `arr` is actually an `NSDictionary` not an `NSArray` and when you iterate over with

```
for (NSDictionary *aaa in arr) [...]
```

you basically go through `NSString` keys, and not the values.